# How to create a java backend with webservices and MySQL?

Tags: java, web-services

Some years ago I made a Swing application that uses a MySQL database. Now I must change this app to work through Internet.

I can connect directly to a MySQL server through Internet, but I think that it's insecure, so I'm thinking about using webservices.

I know I must change lots of code in my current application, and I don't worry about that. But my problem is that I have never used webservices nor server side technologies in Java, and I don't know where to start.

Do you know any good "webservices for dummies" tutorial? I need authentication (and ACL or similar) and database access.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest adaptation: have a look at [apache axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/contents.html), it has everything you need for webservices. That would offer to extend you current applicatino by webservices functionality.

If you need to re-engineer everything, either [spring](http://www.springsource.org/) or [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) should be your friend.

Comment: Bussiness layer must be made from scratch (now in the swing app is all mixed). Why Spring or JEE are my friends? Do you think it's better to build the bussiness layer using Spring or JEE?

Answer (score 0):

Adding web services won't make it any more secure. The best you can do is to enable SSL with JDBC.

Comment: Well, if I add webservices and a complete bussiness layer (in the server) so app can't access directly to the database, I think it's more secure than exposing a MySQL database directly to Internet...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [core servlets](http://coreservlets.com/) site.  There is an EJB tutorial and an AXIS tutorial.  As mentioned by Andreas_D, spring and Java EE are both options.  I suspect you want a simple REST implementation, in which case, spring is a good option.